# How prevent JSON exception

Tags: json, laravel, exception

Laravel (5.5) apparently return the exception in json format instead of whoop page. Where can I disable this annoying behaviour and receive the whoops or the default php exception format?

Comment: Try visiting a page that doesn't exist (simple browser GET request). Do you get the exception in JSON? You should get the normal Whoops if you have `APP_DEBUG=true` in .env. I believe the JSON is returned when you send json headers.

Comment: @devk Yes, i get json as mentioned in the question. currently `APP_DEBUG=true`. I need to receive regular exception for the json header. and this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a request that expects a JSON response, it will give you a JSON response. The following headers trigger a JSON response:

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

OR

```
X-PJAX: true
```

OR

```
Accept: */json or *+json
```

If you do not want this standard behaviour, you can overwrite your exception handler at `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`. Change the `render` function to this (this is a direct copy from `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php`, and always return whoops by neglecting the request header)

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if (method_exists($e, 'render') && $response = $e->render($request)) {
        return Router::toResponse($request, $response);
    } elseif ($e instanceof Responsable) {
        return $e->toResponse($request);
    }

    $e = $this->prepareException($e);

    if ($e instanceof HttpResponseException) {
        return $e->getResponse();
    } elseif ($e instanceof AuthenticationException) {
        return $this->unauthenticated($request, $e);
    } elseif ($e instanceof ValidationException) {
        return $this->convertValidationExceptionToResponse($e, $request);
    }

    return $this->prepareResponse($request, $e);
}
```

Or, add your own logic here to decide what kind of content you would like to return when different headers were given.